# What's the meaning of 0.0.0.0 when setting up zookeeper cluster on multiple ec2 nodes

Tags: docker, hyperledger-fabric, apache-zookeeper

I got a struggling for setting up ***zookeeper cluster*** for hyperledger fabric orderers. By docker zookeeper user forum[https://forums.docker.com/t/cannot-get-zookeeper-to-work-running-in-docker-using-swarm-mode/27109], it says I have to use ***0.0.0.0*** as the host for the server.

I cannot understand why 127.0.0.1 or localhost are not working. Also, if ***0.0.0.0*** is used as a subnet mask, 255.255.255.0 or 0.0.0.1 are also not working.

So what's the meaning of 0.0.0.0 on docker zookeeper for the server on the host.

```
version: '2'
services:
    zk-1:
        extends:
            file: docker-compose-zkbase.yml # common setting for zookeepers
            service: zookeeper
        container_name: zk-1
        hostname: zk-1
        environment:
            - ZOO_MY_ID=1
            - ZOO_SERVERS=server.1=0.0.0.0:2888:3888 server.2=13.125.46.185:2888:3888 server.3=54.180.152.130:2888:3888
```

Finally 0.0.0.0 is good for me, but I still don't understand the exact meaning of 0.0.0.0 for docker zookeeper.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thats' all about networking. When you "open" a socket, that means you create any kind of tcp/udp server, you `bind` the socket to some interface on your local PC.

That means you tell your server to accept connections only from specified interfaces. For example, you could have several ethernet cards onboard and you want your web server to be available only on particular one.

To achieve that you `bind` your server to that interface, specifying IP address.

At the same time there appear to be some special values, which are:

`0.0.0.0` - means your service will be accessible on **all** interfaces. You can connect from both local machine and from any PC, connected to any of your ethernet adapters.

`localhost/127.0.0.1` - means you open your service **locally**. This renders your service available only for connections from local PC. No outside connections will be accepted. This option is valuable for security reasons. Often it is used in reverse-proxy architecture, when unsecure (`http`) connections are opened locally and secure (`https`) - on `0.0.0.0` binding with [`nginx`](http://nginx.org/) as a reverse proxy facilitator.

Answer (score 0):

> Finally 0.0.0.0 is good for me, but I still don't understand the exact meaning of 0.0.0.0 for docker zookeeper.

If for example it have used the localhost network `127.0.0.1` than zookeeper would not be accessible outside the container on port `2888`.

This [answer](https://superuser.com/a/949522) makes an excellent job explaining the difference between 0.0.0.0 and 127.0.0.1.

> What's the difference between 127.0.0.1 and 0.0.0.0?
>
> - `127.0.0.1` is the loopback address (also known as localhost).
> - `0.0.0.0` is a non-routable meta-address used to designate an invalid, >unknown or non applicable target (a no particular address placeholder).
>
> In the context of a route entry, it usually means the default route.
>
> In the context of servers, 0.0.0.0 means "all IPv4 addresses on >the >local machine". If a host has two ip addresses, 192.168.1.1 and >10.1.2.1, >and a server running on the host listens on 0.0.0.0, it will be >reachable >at both of those IPs.